# How can i wait for results from background threads and then display it later?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a question concerning the thread manipulation, may you help me ?

**Context:** Suppose that we have a sequence of works to do as below:

```
while (true) {
    Info input = getInfo( length );
    Result res = Calculation ( input);
    display(res);
}
```

**Problem** I confronted is that sometimes,

1. Calculation(input) method takes too much time which causes serious
   infomation-leak.
2. By all means,  the calculated results should be
   sequentially  displayed

**Question** : So, I would like to know if is there a way so that I can execute the pseudo-code below ?

```
    Machine machine = new Machine();
    // create either a virtual machine or a thread that runs in parallel
    machine.start();
    while (true) {
         Info input = getInfo( length );
         Work work = new Work() {
             Result res = Calculation ( input);
             display(res);

         machine.addWork(work);
    }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

you can call time-consuming method `Calculation(input)` in parallel by submitting tasks to a thread pool. To display calculated results in the same order as `input`s were obtained, use a queue of that tasks and a separate thread.

```
    int poolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Future<Result>> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Result res = queue.take().get();
                display(res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }).start();
    while (true) {
        final Info input = getInfo(length);
        Future<Result> res = pool.submit(() -> {
            return Calculation(input);
        });
        queue.put(res);
    }
```

Comment: Why start a new thread when you have a thread-pool right there?

Comment: @Gray because that task is infinite, and submitting infinite tasks to a thread pool is not good. Thread starvation may happen.

Comment: I do it all of the time @AlexeiKaigorodov.  In this case there is one infinite task so starvation won't happen and the code is cleaner.